# How to build a relationship between a 'user' and 'his comment'?

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin, structure

I'm currently coding a blog to get experience with php(I've made an MVC-Framework), so I am still new to this.

I have two tables important for this question:

`user(id, username, password, registrated)`

`comments(id, content, post_id, comment_author, date, editedAt, editedBy)`

In the `comments`-table `comment_author` is yet not linked to the id of the user, because I was unsure how to actually do this.

A user can write as many comments as he likes, but a comment can only have one author.

`comment_author` has the `username` in it at the moment, but I know I need the `id`(if the user gets deleted and someone else would registrate with this username, the comment would be his).

How should I now structure the tables?

**1.) `comments_author_id` in `comments`-table, `id` in `user` as foreign key:**

In this case I would have the `id` of the Comment author in the `comments`-table, but the `user` would not know about the comments he has written. If I want to show the recent comments of the user on it's profile, could I get them with an `inner-join` query then?

**2.) make a new table `user_comments(id, user_id, comment_id)`**

In this case `user` and `comments` wouldn't know about it's author/comments.

Also I have 'editedBy' in which the username of the last editing user is. Can I somehow link it with the username in the `users`-table or should I also link it with the `id`?

I am really lost with this question since I don't know much about databases; So I appreciate every help and advice I can get.

Please also let me know if I need to give any further information or change something for a better understanding.

Comment: If a comment only has one author option 1 will suffice.

Comment: Agree, I would go for adding a relationship between Users and Comments, adding the UserID to the Comments and a simple join would be enough to get the user's comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It make sense that you go with the first option.

As you said comment has only one author so just use a foreignkey to user table.

In the second option you're creating a hole new table for a data that doesn't need a new table so you're storing data's that you don't need. also you have to write in two different tables which is two different operations for adding a comment and it gives you no extra feature that you can use.

Comment: Thank you, how can I handle 'editedBy' then? I think It should also be linked with the id/the username, can I just also link it with the `user`-id?

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon Yes if you don't need any extra data like old edit or ...

Answer (score 1):

Best way is create a new table `user_comments(id, user_id, comment_id)`. And if you want to track every changed/edit the comment or post it's will better if you create another table for that and if user can only edit then i think it's better to `editedBy` fields not generate. The structure totally upto you what kind of tracking you want to be .

Comment: Thanks at first. If I want to do the same with posts I also would have to make a table `user-posts(id, user_id, post_id)`, right?

Comment: Post have one author. You can use `user_id` with your `posts table` no need to create another one,Cause of A posts only have one author and might be edited by many others that's why it's will better if you track the edited people then you can create one table for `editPosts` . Either you can use `user_id` with your posts table not recoammanded to create another one